# save and write a .vtk polydata file

Tags: python, vtk

I used this puyhon code to convert nifti file to .vtk polydata meshes

```
import itk
import vtk
input_filename = '/home/nour/Bureau/7ans/244/whatIneed/244seg_pve_2.nii.gz'
reader=itk.ImageFileReader[itk.Image[itk.UC,3]].New()
reader.SetFileName(input_filename)
reader.Update()

itkToVtkFilter = itk.ImageToVTKImageFilter[itk.Image[itk.UC,3]].New()
itkToVtkFilter.SetInput(reader.GetOutput())
myvtkImageData = itkToVtkFilter.GetOutput()
print("myvtkImageData")
```

and for saving and writing the .vtk file I used

```
writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetInputData()
writer.SetFileName("/home/nour/Bureau/7ans/244/whatIneed/Output.vtk")
writer.Write()
```

and here the error : 
ERROR: In /work/standalone-x64-build/VTK-source/Common/ExecutionModel/vtkDemandDrivenPipeline.cxx, line 809
vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0x4d9cac0): Input for connection index 0 on input port index 0 for algorithm vtkPolyDataWriter(0x4de3ea0) is of type vtkImageData, but a vtkPolyData is required.

I was wondering as to what would be a good way of writing a vtk Polydata file.
thanks

Comment: Your `writer.SetInputData()` is empty. You may want to use `myvtkImageData` here: `writer.SetInputData(myvtkImageData)`.

Comment: yes I forgot to put it here. but in my code I put it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your image (regular grid) into a polygonal mesh to be able to save it as a **.vtk** file.
For 2D meshes, this can be done using the `vtkExtractSurface` filter.

Another solution would be to use another format (**.vtk** is a legacy format):

- If you want to save a regular grid, you can use the `vtkXMLImageDataWriter`, that uses the **.vti** extension.
- If you want a unstructured mesh, you can use the `vtkXMLPolyDataWriter`, that uses the **.vtp** extension and gives a polygonal mesh. You can also use the `vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter`, that uses the **.vtu** extension and can contain 3D cells.

Answer (score 0):

Images and polygonal meshes are fundamentally different types of data.  You can't just cast an image into a mesh.

To get a mesh you would need to do some type of iso-surface extraction.  Typically you would select some image intensity as the value of your surface, and then you would use an algorithm such as Marching Cubes to create a mesh of that value.

In VTK you can use the vtkContourFilter to create a mesh from an image.  There are a number of examples on the VTK Example web site that show how to use the filter.  Here is one:

https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/ImplicitFunctions/Sphere/

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much. So as I understand : 
1 reading nifti file (segmented file)
2 apply itktovtkfilter
3 creating meshes (using the vtkContourFilter)
4 and finaly convert it to polydata and save it to .vtk file

that's right ??

Comment: PolyData is a mesh.  vtkContourFilter produces as output vtkPolyData